# civicrm upgrade access denied

Tags: drupal, upgrade, accessibility

I have upgraded drupal to 7.72 - (28/8/20). I wanted to update Civicrm from 5.9.1 to 5.10.0 but got "Access denied" after running http://mysite/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1. So I tried going to 5.28.3 but ended up with the same issue.
I am logged in to Drupal on another tab and can log in to drupal.

Comment: pls spell out the steps you did when upgrading civicrm and/or the documentation you followed.

Comment: I used https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/#UpgradingCiviCRMforDrupal7-1.DownloadthemostrecentCiviCRMPackage

My Drupal files director (I assume is " /public_html/drupal/sites/default/files") is set to 755. I never changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I used another browser (edge from chrome), I logged in to Drupal and then used the upgrade command in the same window and it worked.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google Docs Offline, Google Keep Chrome Extension and IE Tab. A good thought for next time. Have you experienced something with these on this issue?